# EmEditorで単独では動くマクロが、インクルードで使おうとすると謎のエラーが出ます

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
このエラーが指摘されるマクロは単独で使うとサクサクに順調に動くですが、インクルードにすると3行目の文字が正しくないというエラーが出てまったく動作しなくなります。

単独で動作するマクロ: `●●●●●●連番結合3.jsee`

```
#include "●●●●●●連番結合3.jsee"
#include "●●●普通の文書にするマクロパーツ.jsee"
```

**EmEditor マクロ エラー**

```
文字が正しくありません。


ファイル: C:\Users\user\Documents\My Macros\●●●●●●連番結合3.jsee

行:      3
```

単独の状態でも動かないなら、何か間違っているのかと思いますが、インクルードにしたときだけ動作しなくなる、文字が正しくないという理由がわかりません。

何が原因になりますでしょうか？
インクルードにする場合は単独でつかうマクロより、造り方や記述方法が異なるのでしょうか？
二番目のマクロをコメントで無効にすると1番目の結合マクロはインクルードでも動作します。
二番目も単独では動きます。二つ合わせると「文字が正しくありません」とでます。
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

解決のご報告
私の記述ミスでした。ありがとうございました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 今回のエラーのことは分かりませんが。単独で動くマクロなら `#include` よりも `editor.ExecuteMacro( "フルパス", eeRunFile | eeMacroLangJScript );` の方が function名の衝突などが避けられて安全だと思います。

Comment: 最初上げられていた画像では改行文字が'↓'と'←'になっていたので改行コードの不整合かもしれません、
ファイルの保存時に改行コードを変更無しになっていれば CR+LF にするとか、設定のプロパティで[ファイル]->
[保存時...]で改行コードをCR+LFとかにしてみてください。私もバッチファイルをUTF-8で保存するときにはまりました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。改行文字が'↓'と'←'になっていたので改行コードの不整合でした。誤解を招く可能性があるので画像は除きました。#include よりも editor.ExecuteMacro( "フルパス", eeRunFile | eeMacroLangJScript );これはさっそく勉強いたします。御厚意､感謝しております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include "●●●普通の文書にするマクロパーツ.jsee"`
の後に改行を追加してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。教えていただき、ありがとうございます。

Comment: お世話になっております。バージョンアップでエラーの指摘パターン集を増やして頂けませんでしょうか？今回のようにまったく関係なかった行がエラーであると指摘されると問題の部分が混乱して気がつきませんでした。
先ほどの事例では2行目を指摘して「改行がありません」とエラーメッセージが出てもらえば即時解決できます。
事例として正規表現で秀丸で動く正規表現がEmEditorで動かないことがよくあります。
推測では、負荷の重い無駄な記述の仕方なのであえて動かないようにOnigmo側などが認めないように作られていると推測しています。
それが一律に構文エラーとしか出ないのですが、エラーとしてはパターンを認識して「戻り読みの中で可変長の記述は無駄な負荷が多いためOni○○では動作しません。記述を変えてください｣とかです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: これは不具合でしたので、既にこちらでは修正しています。次に公開されるバージョンでは修正されています。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。頼もしい高速動作とバージョンアップの迅速さ、たいへんありがたく存じます。